# how to install vmware tools on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware

I had installed the newest `VMware` server on `Windows 7`. I am running a VM with the newest `Ubuntu 11.04`. The version of `VMware Remote Console is 2.5.0 build-122581` (I guess it's the newest at the moment of writing).

I am trying to install the VMware tools on my Ubuntu VM. On the previous version of VM there was a simple menu item, called `"install vmware tools"` that did all the job. On the current version (that comes with a web interface for some reason) the "install vmware tools" only causes some directory to be mounted from inside the Ubuntu. The mounted directory has 2 files: `rpm` and `tar.gz`. I wanted to install the `rpm`, so that the package manager will recognize the installation and everything will be kinda smooth and well-formed. However, not sure that `rpm` suits Ubuntu, but `deb` (there is no file like this).

In short, is `tar.gz` my only option or I can still install `rpm` in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPM is for Red-Hat like package management, and therefore not suitable for Ubuntu. Just untar the `.tar.gz` file.

```
tar xvf VMwareTools*.tar.gz
```

and then see the corresponding Readme- or Installation-files for help. If I'm not completely wrong, there is an installer script. Just `cd` to the newly extracted directory and run the installer script with `root` permissions:

```
cd vmware-tools-distrib
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Finally, open the `vmware-toolbox`:

```
sudo vmware-toolbox
```

<sub>This is what I gathered from my memory and the Ubuntu documentation, so if they haven't changed anything, it should work like this.</sub>

Comment: Correct in general (and perfectly answers the question). however, installing took me to a different domain of problems, but that's (as I've said) a different subject. Thanks!

Comment: you can most certainly use rpm (via [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto)) on Debian-based distros such as Ubuntu, though they're not native, and .debs are better :)

Comment: @warren Yeah, I've used `alien` before, but I didn't want to go into the troubles of that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its not enough to run the install you have to also run /usr/bin$ sudo ./vmware-config-tools.pl to get tools support compiled into the kernel.

Let us know how it goes and if your vmware tools service starts.

Comment: since then at the end of the day, our sysadmin took control and solved it by a different procedure. I think it was: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools. Still the answer above appears valid to me, since my initial intention was to install it in a different way, but unzipping etc was the only option. Thanks a lot for your valuable update.